# Permanently delete directory from versioned S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If you have an AWS S3 bucket with 1000's of files and 100's of directories, with versioning enabled, how can you easily and quickly delete an entire "folder", leaving behind no trace.

- Permanently, delete the folder, including all objects, versions, and delete markers.
- Not the whole bucket. Not one file either. Rather, a "folder" and its contents, recursively.
- Ideally using the console. Next option, the aws cli. Next option, boto.

What I tried: in the console, if "Show versions" is not enabled, you can click on the directory, and delete it. But that actually leaves behind all the versions and the delete markers. A lot of things. So, it doesn't fully accomplish the current task.

If "Show versions" is enabled, and you click on a *directory* then deletion is disabled.  It is prevented.

I have written a somewhat messy convoluted bash script using the aws cli: `aws s3api delete-objects`. But it is not ideal, for such a simple goal: " delete a 'directory' ". I'll post the script as an answer if a more elegant solution is not available.

---

To explain why this is an interesting and even "important" question...  consider how common and useful this command is, in Linux:

```
rm -rf dir
```

It deletes a directory, and leaves nothing behind. Next, what is the equivalent in AWS S3?

```
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://your_bucket_name/foo/
```

Likewise, it deletes a directory completely.

Finally, what about the situation where versioning has been enabled on an S3 bucket?

You'd like to use `aws s3 rm --recursive`, but all the previous versions of objects will still be left in S3. You'll still be charged for storage.  Nothing will actually be deleted. There should be an *option* to add a `--permanent` flag, to clean up the left-over objects.  In the absence of that option how can you accomplish the equivalent of `rm -rf dir`.

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear. You haven't even specified what programming language do you se for your script.

Comment: aws s3api delete-objects but you have to do it for all sub keys groups containing objects, or each folder within a bucket and folders included there within.

Comment: @Sam I'm experiencing the same issue and to me, it seems the best solution here (for the lack of an official way) is actually your script. Could you please post it?

Comment: @user3738870 https://gist.github.com/sdarwin/dcb4afc68f0952ded62d864a6f720ccb

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Lifecycle Rules** to achieve what you want. You would need to create a Lifecycle Rule with the rule scope option set to `Limit the scope of this rule using one or more filters` and enter the `Prefix` (that would be your "dir"). In the `Lifecycle rule actions` section select this two options: `Expire current versions of objects` and `Permanently delete noncurrent versions of objects`. For the `Days after ...` option on both cases set value to `1`.
You would need to wait for a day so that the Lifecycle Rule takes action, though.

Comment: Clever solution!! Does require waiting a day.